# Javascript solution to auto-pausing video when focus away from window

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I am going through a series of tutorial videos and unfortunately, they are set to pause whenever I move my focus away from the window. I've found lots of posts addressing how to generate this kind of behavior, but I'm not skilled enough to reverse-engineer them.  I imagine some kind of timed mouseclick or other forms of simulated interaction.

Comment: The `window` has an event called `blur` when you move away. Simply pause when it occurs, unpause when you `focus`. `window.addEvenListener('blur', e => video.paused = true)`

Comment: Please, don't do this.  A lot of folks have a lot of windows up at the same time.  Just because another window has focus doesn't mean the video isn't being seen.

Comment: Maybe question is not clear, I'm looking for a way to overcome this annoying behavior as a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below code snippet, this might be useful:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function playVid() {
    vid.play();
}

function pauseVid() {
    vid.pause();
}

vid.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  console.log('focused');
  playVid();
});

vid.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  console.log('not focused');
  pauseVid();
});
```

```html
<video id='myVideo' width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called 'blur' associated with moving focus from a window. Videos that auto-pause when the window isn't active have a line similar to:

```
window.addEventListener("blur", function() {video.pause()})
```

You can use Chrome developer tools to easily remove this event listener, which will allow the video to continue playing even if it isn't the active window.

Use *CMD + Option + i* to open Chrome Developer Tools (or select View, Developer, Developer Tools from the menu bar), then navigate to the Elements tab. Drag the window to the left until it contains two columns, then click "Event Listeners" in the second column - it will be near the top, right corner of the tool window (You may need to click the double arrow to reveal additional menu items). Find and select the 'blur' item from the list, then click 'Remove.'

This will prevent the video from pausing when the window isn't active.

See the screenshot below if you're having trouble finding the Event Listeners menu item. If the developer tools is wide enough to be two vertical columns, you'll find it on the right side at the top.

[Google Chrome Developer Tools with Event Listeners selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTV5s.png)